# Grabbing a URL from json and playing the video. (swift/tvos)

Tags: json, swift, parsing, tvos

I want to grab a single `URL` in my `JSON` file, which I have done successfully and parse it correctly.

I can not get the `AVPlayer` to handle the parse url any help would be sooo grateful! Thanks!

```
import UIKit
import AVKit

class TrailerVC: UIViewController {

//calling var from different cell where it has the data    
var film: FilmCell! 

//film.filmvideoFile stores the url.

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let videoURL = URL(string: "\(film.filmvideoFile)" )
        let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)
        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        playerLayer.frame = view.bounds
        view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        player.play()
    }

}
```

Comment: what is the value of `film.filmvideoFile`?

Comment: The value is pulled from a json URL, string. The value is a URL .mp4

Comment: if let voteAverage = filmDictionary["speakerName"] as? String {
            self.voteAverage = voteAverage
        }
        
        //path to image from JSON
        if let path = filmDictionary["image"] as? String {
            self.posterPath = "\(path)"
        }
        //path to synopsis from JSON
        if let videoFile = filmDictionary["videoFile"] as? String {
        self.videoFile = videoFile
}

Comment: You can edit your question and include the code from your comment, so that it's formatted and more readable. Does the URL point to a local file? Or is it a remote one, like `https://example.com/URL.mp4`? It's not clear from your comment.